# Get attributes from a returned function in Python

Tags: python, closures

```
def outerFunc(number):
    if number < 0:
        def innerFunc(factor):
            return number * factor
    else:
        def innerFunc(summand):
            return number + summand
    return innerFunc

x = outerFunc(-8)
print(x(4))
```

The result of the print statement is `-32`, as expected. I'm using Python 3.5.2

I would like to ask two questions regarding this code snippet:

1. Is it possible to access the inner function's `number` property, after having bound `innerFunc` to `x` with the statement `x = outerFunc(-8)`? In other words: is it possible to directly access the preserved value of `number`, in this case `-8`, after having performed the closure?
2. Is it good programming style to return a function, depending on the evaluation of an if-statement? Personally, I think there is better approach, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's not good style to try to access internal structures. Why do you want to get `number`?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Accessing those structures is a pretty bad idea. I would never use it in any kind of productive code. In this case I merely seek understanding as to how closures work on the inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to access the inner function's `number` property

It's not a property. You can technically access it, but not in a particularly nice way:

```
number = x.__closure__[0].cell_contents
```

> Is it good programming style to return a function, depending on the evaluation of an if-statement?

Yeah, it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestion worked just fine. I'm sorry, if I denoted `number` a property. I'm not sure about the correct term in this context. How would you call it?

Comment: @6q9nqBjo: Closure variable.

Answer (score -1):

1. No.
2. Rarely, but there are cases where it could make sense. If you have to ask the question, you should probably consider the answer to be 'no,' at least for now.